# catch MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException in javafx

Tags: javafx

I tried to catch (MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException) but eclipse asked me to remove try and catch
My question is how can I detect MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException.
Because I want to update data, and my Table contained a foreign key, and when I tried to add data that doesn’t exist, this Error appears 
therefore I want to know If data exist so I change it, if not I add it 
here is my code :

```html
     col_observ.setOnEditCommit(
         new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Information, String>>() {
             @Override
             public void handle(CellEditEvent<Information, String> t) {
                 co.connexion_open();
                 co.insert("update user set obser'"+t.getNewValue()+"' where id="+t.getRowValue().getId()+"");
                 co.connexion_close();
             }
         }
     );
```

Where col_obsev is a tableColumn, that contained a TextfieldsTableCell, so when I edit the data in this a cell, I have to update it in DB,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That kind of exception is thrown when you try to let's say set data in a cell to null when the constraints of the table do not allow this.
When eclipse ask you to remove the catch clause then the code in the try block does not throw that exception.
But it's hard to answer the question without having any details. Could you post a code segment and your table definition please?

Comment: Maybe just do a 'select count(*) from thetablename where...' before you try a blind update. If this returns 0 the requested data does not exist.